# Reddit Dataset including who wrote which post? and who are the up/down voters?

Tags: dataset, reddit

I need a sample of reddit dataset including the users' voting with both writer's userId/username and voters' userId/username. I need a dataset in which I can see which username writes which posts? and which usernames give up/down votes to this post/comment. 
Do we have a public available one? Or I have to use their API for this purpose?
Any other dataset with users' posts/comments and users' voting will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While authorship of comments and posts is generally public, votes are private, unless the user has explicitly enabled public vote records for themselves.  As such, you're not going to find any sort of representative dataset that includes vote history.